# How to create variable of type VectorSearchAlgorithmConfiguration

Tags: python

Following this tutorial, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-get-started-vector , instead of using the `json` `put` method, I am trying to use `python` API.

I want to create a variable of type `VectorSearchAlgorithmConfiguration`, as defined in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-search-documents/azure.search.documents.indexes.models.vectorsearchalgorithmconfiguration?view=azure-python

As per my understanding, the api takes two definite parameters, the 3rd (and maybe more) dependon the value of 2nd parameter. Eg. `HnswParameters` for `kind="hnsw"` - if I map from the `json` to `api`

I created the following two definitions

```
hnswParameters = HnswParameters(m=4,ef_construction= 400, ef_search= 500, metric= "cosine")
vectorSearchAlgorithm = VectorSearchAlgorithmConfiguration(name = "my-hnsw-vector-config-1",kind="hnsw",hnswParameters=hnswParameters)
```

but I get error `hnswParameters is not a known attribute of class <class 'azure.search.documents.indexes._generated.models._models_py3.VectorSearchAlgorithmConfiguration'> and will be ignored`. How do I provide `hnswParameters` ?

I later tried to create instance of `HnswVectorSearchAlgorithmConfiguration` as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-search-documents/azure.search.documents.indexes.models.hnswvectorsearchalgorithmconfiguration?view=azure-python-preview but when I import

```
from azure.search.documents.indexes.models import (  
 ...   HnswVectorSearchAlgorithmConfiguration
)
```

I get error `ImportError: cannot import name 'HnswVectorSearchAlgorithmConfiguration' from 'azure.search.documents.indexes.models' (c:\Users\manuchadha\...\demo-data\aoai-openai\aoai-code\.venv\Lib\site-packages\azure\search\documents\indexes\models\__init__.py)`

Update.

Thanks Tim for pointing in right direction. I created `HnswAlgorithmConfiguration`
Probably this will work, I still have to test. The code compiles though

```
hnswParameters = HnswParameters(m=4,ef_construction= 400, ef_search= 500, metric= "cosine")
vectorSearchAlgorithm = HnswAlgorithmConfiguration(name = "my-hnsw-vector-config-1",parameters=hnswParameters)
vectorSearchProfile = VectorSearchProfile(name="my-vector-profile",algorithm_configuration_name="my-hnsw-vector-config-1")
```

Comment: Why aren't you using `HnswAlgorithmConfiguration`, as the documentation suggests?

Comment: thanks. updated the question if you could help in that as well please.